# Android WebView eval not working

Tags: javascript, android-webview

The eval function in Android WebView is not working. Here is the code I am executing. Line 2 is printing undefined.

```
console.log("Script json" + eval(scriptJson.Script+" \n function test() {alert(1233);}"));
console.log("is functions loaded "+ window.test);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem actually I am running eval from another js object

```
myobj.init = function () {
   console.log("Script json" + eval(scriptJson.Script+" \n function test() {alert(1233);}"));
   console.log("is functions loaded "+ window.test);
}
```

Instead if I change it to

```
myobj.init = function () {
   console.log("Script json" + window.eval(scriptJson.Script+" \n function test() {alert(1233);}"));
   console.log("is functions loaded "+ window.test);
}
```

Its working...